# How to execute a TRIGGER in MSSQl?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Am having two table like *Student* and *StudentHistory* in SQL Server, if any change happen in the *Student* table that Trigger should update *StudentHistory* table.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
  Id int,
  Name varchar(20),
  Dept varchar(10),
  Age int,
  Cratedby int,
  CreatedTime datetime,
  Modeifideby int,
  ModifiedTime datetime,
  Flag varchar(5)
)
```

History table,

```
CREATE TABLE StudentHistory (
  Id int,
  Actiontaken varchar(50),
  ActionTime dateTime,
  Cratedby int,
)
```

Trigger,

```
CREATE TRIGGER  wsrd.tr_Student on
wsrd.Student
AFTER INSERT
AS

insert into wsrd.StudentHistory
           (Actiontaken,ActionTime,Cratedby) 
    (SELECT concat('Inserted-',i.id),i.CreatedTime,i.Cratedby from wsrd.Student s, inserted i where s.id=i.Id);
GO
```

The condition is,

1. Trigger should get execute only if column Modeifideby, ModifiedTime  and Flag is inserted in the Student table.

   2. If Id,Name, Dept , age, CreatedTime and Flag inserted means that trigger should not get execute.

How can achieve this?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: inserted or updated? Or both? What about deleted?

Comment: Homework, and you want us to do it for you... At least show us your current code attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trStudent
ON dbo.[Student]
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.[StudentHistory]
        (Id, Actiontaken, ActionTime, Cratedby)  
    SELECT i.Id, i.Flag , i.CreatedTime, i.Cratedby 
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE (i.Modeifideby > '' OR i.ModifiedTime > '01-01-1900' or i.Flag > '')
END
```

Comment: Thanks. Checking > '' is the right way to achieve this

Comment: Or perhaps `IS NOT NULL`?